# When $ e^x$ ~ $ e^{-2x}$ ? - Numerical analysis

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

For what $x$, $ e^x  $ ~ $e^{-2x}$ ? And how one can change this expression to avoid significant digits loss? I am able to think only about $x =0$, but then both are equal and you lose nothing.

Comment: instead of $e^x$ and $e^{-2x}$ consider $t$ and $t^{-2}$, when are they almost equal?

Answer (score 0):

It is only for $x=0$, since for negative values of $x$, $e^{-2x}$ is increasing and greater than $1$, and $e^x$ is less than $1$. And similarly for positive values of $x$. So, there exists only one solution for this equation. You can check this by plotting the curve.

Comment: I fixed your answer. Maybe English is not your first language, so perfection is not expected. But, even so, you probably know that sentences are supposed to start with an upper-case letter, commas and periods don't have spaces before them, and "U" is not a word. You're writing mathematics, not sending a text message to your buddies.

Comment: Thanks , next time i will try .